# Missing dependency while product export

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I created an RCP Plug-in project using template "Eclipse 4 RCP Application" (Plugin A)
I then created another Plugin-in project to contribute to Plugin A(Plugin B)

In the MANIFEST.MF file of Plugin A, I added Plugin B in the list of "Required Plug-ins"
under "Dependencies" tab, since Plugin A uses some classes defined in Plugin B.

When I try to run my product file, which is in Plugin A, it runs without any errors but when I try to export my product file using "Eclipse export wizard", it fails with below error
"A problem occured while invoking the director"

When I logged the error to a log file it showed below message
Missing requirement: Plugin A requires 'osgi.bundle; Plugin B' but it could not be found.

Eclipse is not able to find Plugin B. Am I missing something here? Are there any more configuration required?

Comment: The xxx.product file configures what is in the exported RCP, everything required must be listed there.  Note that 'Export Eclipse Product' is now in maintenance mode, the only supported method of building an RCP is [Maven + Tycho](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks!. I added the dependency in the "Contents" tab of the product file and it solved my issue. I'll also take a look at Tycho